# Как сделать только один коммит из локальной ветки в remote

Tags: git, git-rebase

Есть удаленный репозиторий

```
x1->x2->x3
          \master
```

Я сделал его форк и локально новую ветку

```
          /master
x1->x2->x3
          \y1->y2->y3
                     \local-develop
```

Как мне теперь сделать push-request с последним коммитом так, что бы не были видно всей истории коммитов?

```
              /master
x1->x2->x3->y3
          \y1->y2->y3
                     \local-develop
```

Цель в том, что бы добавить результат работы в удаленный репозиторий в отдельную ветку, при этом не захламляя удаленный репозиторий лишними кометами с историей разработки.

Я пробовал сделать так

```
git checkout local-develop
git rebase -i master
*squash all commit*
```

Но получается что они сбиваются в одни в local-develop ветке.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Схемы отличные ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Это так не работает.

Проблема в том, что коммит, *семантически*, это **набор изменений**, а не состояние.

Поэтому чтобы отправить последнее состояние, нужно отправить набор изменений от начального (`x3`, не включительно) до конечного (`y3`).

И раз вы хотите представить этот набор одним коммитом, то вам придётся сделать **один** коммит, содержащий в себе изменения `y1`..`y3`. С помощью `rebase -i` вы это и сделали.

Если при этом вы не хотите терять исходные коммиты, можно "сплющивание" (squash) сделать в отдельной ветке (просто перед началом ребейза сделав `git checkout -b local-develop-squashed`, находясь в ветке `local-develop`).

После ребейза получится такое состояние:

```
x1->x2->x3-\ {master}
           |
           |->y1->y2->y3 {local-develop}
           |
           \->z1 {local-develop-squashed}
```

В ветке `local-develop-squashed` по сравнению с `master` выходит один красивый коммит.
Из этой ветки и нужно делать pull request.

У этого, конечно, есть проблемы. Если вы захотите этот pull request доделать, вам **придётся делать `push --force` каждый раз, что в общем случае очень опасно**. Поэтому "на посмотреть" можно загрузить и исходную историю из кучи коммитов, и только когда дадут "добро", сделать из кучи коммитов один "прямо на месте" и сделать **один раз** `push --force`.

А ещё некоторые пользуются при мердже PR опцией `--no-ff`, а историю смотрят с помощью `git log --first-parent master`, в результате чего детальная история фича-веток не показывается, а PR выглядят, как отдельные коммиты. И для этого не нужно никакое шаманство с перезаписью коммитов и пушем "силой".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Доделать pull request т.е. изменит его? Почему нужен будет --force?

Comment: @DmitryDonkey потому что если вы хотите, чтобы в любой момент времени в PR был только один коммит, вам придётся перезаписать тот коммит, что там уже есть.

Comment: ЕМНИП, на гитхабе можно делать [Merge squash](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, или так, тогда вообще нет смысла заморачиваться с ручным склеиванием.

Comment: @D-side Я предполагал что коммиты в удаленной ветке будут "стакаться" от пуша к пушу - z1->z2->z3->... Просто не будет видно "реализации" - промежуточных коммитов.

Comment: @DmitryDonkey в гите нет понятия "реализации". Коммиты либо отдельные, либо слитые. Если вам нужны оба варианта, придётся держать оба локально. Ну или я предложил в последнем абзаце чуть менее деструктивный вариант.